# `Rmpi` unable to access all cores

Tags: r, mpi, openmpi

When trying to spawn slaves in `Rmpi`, I get the error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 2
slots that were requested by the application:

  /opt/usern/R/4.0.4/lib/R/library/Rmpi/Rslaves.sh

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots
available for use.
```

I know I have the hardware for several slaves:

```
> parallel::detectCores()
[1] 4
```

But how do I configure `openmpi` to have enough slots for several slaves?

Minimal reprex:

`mpi.spawn.Rslaves(nslaves = workers)`

I'm using CentOS 8, `Rmpi` 0.6-9.1 with `openmpi` 4.1.1.

Comment: How politically incorrect. Was R written in the 18th century?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout [`Rmpi`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Rmpi) is a contributed package, its maintainer is responsible for it, not R. And the main question seems to be *"But how do I configure openmpi to have enough slots for several slaves?"*

Comment: @VictorEijkhout It’s MPI’s terminology. And as far as computer science history is concerned, MPI was indeed written in what amounts to the 18th century. Maybe the terminology will be changed at some point.

Comment: @KonradRudolph MPI has long since scrubbed such terminology. Maybe R will finally enter the 20th century too. Besides, MPI is not based on a master/worker model, so I doubt that that MPI standard used this term much, if at all.

Comment: does `parallel::detectCores()` detect cores or hyperthreads? In Open MPI, the default is `slot == core`. You can have `slot == hyperthread` by `mpirun --use-hwthread-cpus ...` or have unlimited slots (it is up to you not to spawn too many tasks in order to optimize resources) with `mpirun --oversubscribe ...`

Comment: The very politically correct MPI standard uses the "Manager-worker" terminology.

Comment: Dated terminology yes, unfortunately the package is not maintained on an open tracker so I can't make a fork to adjust that. Also that's useful to know @Giles but I don't have any control over the calls to `mpirun` from within R, MPI is interfaced with through the Rmpi package. It works well with openmpi 1.10.7 however I cannot find an RPM to install this to Centos 8 with unfortunately.

Comment: Try to `export OMPI_MCA_rmaps_base_oversubscribe=true` before invoking `R`

Comment: Are you using a bash script to start your R-script? I'm also on Centos using openmpi and Rmpi to run an R script in parallel on an HPC. Because it is on an HPC I have to use a bash script (determining the number of requested workers and starting the Rscript with mpirun) to start the parallel run. I than use sbatch -n #numberOfNodes Filename.sh to start the parallel run.

Comment: `export OMPI_MCA_rmaps_base_oversubscribe=true` works, when I call R from the command line - thanks @GillesGouaillardet The only question now is how to get it working from within RStudio..

Comment: @JKupzig not using a bash script, it's not working anywhere i.e. R from command line, from with RStudio etc. (except when using `export OMPI_MCA_rmaps_base_oversubscribe=true`)